url-state-machine.js quarantined when attempting to install Expo (npm install)
Today my Norton virsus software Quarantined url-state-machine.js which is in the package whatwg-url package that is used by Expo (expo@51.0.38) and jest-expo@51.0.4
I checked for updates and none are released for expo, so even removing jest testing, I can no longer run my Expo project.
├─┬ expo@51.0.38
│ └─┬ @expo/cli@0.18.30
│   └─┬ node-fetch@2.7.0
│     └── whatwg-url@5.0.0
└─┬ jest-expo@51.0.4
  └─┬ jest-environment-jsdom@29.7.0
    └─┬ jsdom@20.0.3
      ├─┬ data-urls@3.0.2
      │ └── whatwg-url@11.0.0 deduped
      └── whatwg-url@11.0.0

Anyone have this same issue? Any work arounds? I know I can disable my anti-virus, but the package has be identified to have malware and don't want to be at risk
I have checked for updates from whatwg-url directly with no updates. Investigated the use of the package and checked for updates from Expo and there is none defined. I removed the jest dependency for now, but seems like I cannot be the only one in this situation

Norton updated and now it lets me install packages without moving to quarantine. Will monitor and reopen if file becomes issue.
